# Domain model using Scala, if OSGI bundled on Classpath (global)?

Tags: java, scala, osgi

If I build a JAR around my Scala domain model project and use an OSGI manifest, will all of these Scala objects be available on the classpath to others in the OSGI container?

Comment: Depends on how that manifest looks like. If you Export the relevant packages, then others can Import them.

Comment: Ah, so I would need to explicitly export the packages for my domain model objects.

Comment: Yes. OSGi is all about explicit dependency management between packages. Your bundle gets wired up to other bundles' classes using these Export/Import declarations. The upshot is that all your "implementation detail packages" (and even dependencies) remain completely hidden to the outside, so that you can change them more easily later.